# How to perform a logout test with php unit in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-passport

I have the following method built, however it gives me a 500 status error and not a 200.

```php
public function test_logout_success()
{
    $user = User::factory()->create();
    $role = Role::findByName('admin', 'api');
    $user->assignRole($role);

    Passport::actingAs($user,'api');

    $token = $user->createToken(config('create-token'))->accessToken;

    $user->save();

    $this->get('/logout', [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
    ])->assertStatus(200);
}
```

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong really, any help?, thanks.

I tried to login as follows:

```php
$requestData = [
    'email' => $user->email,
    'password' => 'P@ssword'
];
        
$response = $this->actingAs($user)->post('/login', $requestData);
```

To later get the token from the response with:

```php
$response->json('data.token')
```

This time I receive a 403.

But it doesn't work either, it's not clear to me if the user is still logged in sincerily.

```php
public function test_logout_success()
{
    $user = User::factory()->create();
    $role = Role::findByName('admin', 'api');
    $user->assignRole($role);
    
    $requestData = [
        'email' => $user->email,
        'password' => 'P@ssword'
    ];
    
    $response = $this->actingAs($user)->post('/api/v1/auth/login', $requestData);
    
    $this->get('/api/v1/auth/logout', [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $response->json('data.token'),
    ])->assertStatus(200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right away I see a problem with the way you're making requests: `Authorization: Bearer ...` is a header. You're passing it as data.

Try making your requests like this:

```php
$response = $this->withHeaders(['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token])->get('/logout');

$response->assertStatus(200);
```

And then, to assert you've been logged out, you can use `assertGuest($guard = null)` Since you're using the api, I suppose the guard in this case is `api` (check your config/auth.php file).

```php
public function test_logout_success()
{
    // ARRANGE
    /**
     * create user
     * log it in
     * make sure it's logged in with the api guard by writing a pre-assertion
     */
    $this->assertAuthenticated('api');

    // ACT
    /**
     * hit the logout endpoint
     */
    $response = $this->withHeaders(['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token])->get('/logout');

    // ASSERT
    /**
     * make sure the server responds with a successful http status
     * and user has been logged out of the api guard
     */
    $response->assertStatus(200);
    $this->assertGuest('api');
}
```

- https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-tests#customizing-request-headers
- https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-tests#authentication-assertions